# Obtain text within script tag using Jsoup in android

Tags: java, android, jsoup

How to get value `http://htvlive.1c656bad.cdnviet.com/fcf0d4d9ebc07ce9de74aff5562e4d2d1480305561/htv7.720p.stream/playlist.m3u8` using Jsoup?

[image: nondescript screen shot]

```
String url = "htvonline.com.vn/livetv/htv7-hd-34336E61.html";
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements scriptElements = document.getElementsByTag("script");
for (Element element :scriptElements ){
    for (DataNode node : element.dataNodes()) {
        System.out.println(""+node.getWholeData().toString());
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------");
}
```

Comment: can you give the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same url as in the `li` element with id `play_video`, so select that element and read the `data-source` attribute.

**Example Code**

```
try {
    String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://htvonline.com.vn/livetv/htv7-hd-34336E61.html").userAgent(userAgent).get();

    String url = doc.select("#play_video").first().attr("data-source");

    System.out.println(url);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Output**

```
http://htvlive.1c656bad.cdnviet.com/903e50e4d06db85d81fc84b49abec4081480474746/htv7.720p.stream/playlist.m3u8
```

Comment: @XuânMai Glad I could help, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hello Frederic Klein . can you give me skype or facebook so that I can talk to you

Comment: @XuânMai no, the answer is not accepted. If your issue is not resolved and your question can be extended (within the scope of stackoverflow), please post a follow up question here.

Comment: Please Support http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004834/obtain-value-within-script-tag-using-jsoup-android