# Obtain value within script tag using Jsoup Android

Tags: java, jsoup

How to get value `http://htvmoblive.1c656bad.cdnviet.com/5720e8c257ab335e961c381db953df0e1481099170/htv9.720p.stream/playlist.m3u8` using Jsoup?

[image: screenshot]

```
    String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36";
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://hplus.com.vn/xem-tivi-htv3-2535.html").userAgent(userAgent).get();
            Element description = doc.select("video[id=ios-player]").first();
            imgSrc2 = description.attr("src");
```

Please support

Comment: Wehere do you want to get the value from?

Comment: @LutzHorn i want to get data url http://hplus.com.vn/xem-tivi-htv3-2535.html

Comment: There is no such link on this page. Are you interested in the `<input id="link-live">`?

Comment: If you move the browser form mobile then you will see the form as in the photo.